# Getting attribute error while joining 2 tables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There are 2 tables category, sub_category that i want to join through common column id, category. While doing so I'm getting attribute error. I want category's data first then sub_category's data.

Models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    store_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='category')
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sub_category'
```

Views.py:

```
class CategoryView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def post(self, request):
        queryset = Category.objects.all().exclude(parent_id=0)
        serializer = CategorySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serialzer.py:

```
class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "category", "sub_category", "is_active"]
        model = SubCategory


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub_category_data = SubCategorySerializer(read_only=True, source='id')

    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "category", "image", "is_active", "parent_id","sub_category_data"]
        model = Category
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `category` on serializer `SubCategorySerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'category'.
```

Comment: Why are u using `source=id`?

Comment: category have field name 'id' which i want to link with SubCategorySerializer

Comment: What will be the difference if `source='id'` is removed?

Comment: no error, but sub_category_data is  not shown in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your serializer to

```
class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "category", "sub_category", "is_active"]
        model = SubCategory

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub_category_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "category", "image", "is_active", "parent_id", 
                 "sub_category_data"]
        model = Category

    @staticmethod
    def get_sub_category_data(obj):
        sub =  SubCategory.objects.filter(category_id=obj.id)
        return SubCategorySerializer(sub, many=True).data
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks dude